# ViewPager FragmentPagerAdapter Nullpointer

Tags: android, fragment, android-viewpager

I got this error by using the ViewPager in the Android [Support package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).  from the Horizontal View Swiping with [ViewPager Tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

```
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:347)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:342)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:649)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:783)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12728)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12728)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12728)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12728)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12728)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-19 13:07:25.950: E/AndroidRuntime(16382):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Just in case anyone doesn't read the comments of passsy's answer, here is a summary of the useful answers:

1) Examine your `getItem(int index)` method very closely and look for any logic, scenarios or missing 'break' statements which might cause you to end up with a `null` fragment.

2) Check that the count returned by `getCount()` matches the number of fragments returned in `getItem(int index)`.

3) Examine your imports and ensure you aren't mixing `android.app.Fragment` with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The error stack is thrown on all three accounts. In my case I had not implemented a Fragment class inflating the view for a particular tab. I was under the assumption that returning a null from the getItem() method would render the tab (titles) without their associated Fragments in my Activity. Returning a Fragment for each tab from getItem() solved the issue for me.

Comment: happened to me and option 1 was the ticket - just sharing - used a switch case inside getItem(int index), and the case labels were 0, 2, 3, also causes same exception. thanks.

Answer (score 18):

It's a simple solution. I mixed **android.app.Fragment** and **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**

hope this helps someone

Comment: Are you sure that was the fix?  I have the exact same stacktrace but no instances of android.app.Fragment ...

Comment: you have android.app.Activity or android.app.FragmentActivity? use everything from android.support.v4.app

Comment: I found the problem, one of the switch cases in my getItem() was falling out to the bottom where there was a default return null.

Comment: Damm, had a null pointer in getItem as well. So hint to everybody with this error: Check your getItem with a fine comb.

Comment: brk3, maybe you can add an answer to that effect? Helped me out too!

Comment: This happened to me because I was returning a different number in getCount() than the number of tabs.

Answer (score 6):

If [getItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#getItem%28int%29) in your Adapter returns null that can cause a null pointer exception.