# Layout Inflater using ViewPager throws NullPointerException

Tags: android

I'm working on a quiz based app. Each question has 4 options. Question is a text view while for options I'm using a viewpager so that the user can swipe the 4 options that will be loaded dynamically from the server.
I'm getting `NullPointerException` for Layout inflater.
This is the line I get null value:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);
class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter { 
    int NumberOfPages = 4;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> option1List; .....
```

Help and guidance is highly appreciated.

```
Error :
```

> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at quizapp.android.mohit.com.quizapp.MyAdapter.instantiateItem(Questions.java:485)

Here is my Mainactivity code :

```
  public class Questions extends ActionBarActivity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);
  dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
adapter = new MyAdapter(option1List, option2List, option3List,option4List);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    int NumberOfPages = 4;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View itemView;
    ArrayList<String> option1List;
    ArrayList<String> option2List;
    ArrayList<String> option3List;
    ArrayList<String> option4List;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> option1List, ArrayList<String> option2List, ArrayList<String> option3List, ArrayList<String> option4List) {
        this.option1List = option1List;
        this.option2List = option2List;
        this.option3List = option3List;
        this.option4List = option4List;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return NumberOfPages;
    }

    public boolean isViewFromObject(View container, Object obj) {
        return container == obj;
        // return container == (View) obj;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);
        // Declare Variables
        TextView option1, option2, option3, option4;
        // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
        option1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_option1);
        option2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_option2);
        option3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_option3);
        option4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_option4);
        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        option1.setText(option1List.get(0));
        option2.setText(option2List.get(0));
        option3.setText(option3List.get(0));
        option4.setText(option4List.get(0));
        // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object obj) {
       container.removeView((LinearLayout)obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20412475/1527458

Comment: What line is the error happening in and where are you declaring the field "context"?

Comment: @barq : This is the line i get null value :
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);

class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        int NumberOfPages = 4;
        Context context;
        ArrayList<String> option1List;
      .....

Comment: you need to pass getSupportFragmentManager() to your view pager adapter

Comment: @Mina Fawzy : I'm not using fragments. I'm implementing Viewpager with PagerAdapter rather than using fragments.

Comment: `adapter = new MyAdapter(option1List, option2List, option3List,option4List);`
where are you retrieving these values in adapter . you say 4 options can be swiped in viewpager then y 4 textviews are needed.. one textview should be inflated right

Comment: @Dhina : Thanks. I just forgot that I need to take a single text view & not 4 text views.

Comment: Hope your issue is solved.

Comment: @Dhina : Yes dear !! Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

create a `MyAdapter` constructor which has `Context` as one of its parameters e.g

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String>arrayList;
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String>, Context context){
this.context = context;
this.arrayList = arrayList;
```

in you activity, just initialize the adapter by passing in arraylist and context like

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(myList, getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        int NumberOfPages = 4;
        Context context;
        ArrayList<String> option1List;
        ArrayList<String> option2List;
        ArrayList<String> option3List;
        ArrayList<String> option4List;
        public MyAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> option1List, ArrayList<String> option2List, ArrayList<String> option3List, ArrayList<String> option4List) {
            this.context = context;
            this.option1List = option1List;
            this.option2List = option2List; and so on
        }

Answer (score 0):

You should try to inflate the view in another way such as using static methods of
`LayoutInflater`. You should also stop using application context instead you should use your activity as context.

Code :-

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

you crate Adapter object and pass four ArrayList in it but In your adapter you are not defined your construtor.....please define it.See the code below

try this.....

```
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    int NumberOfPages = 4;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<type you define> option1List, ArrayList<type you define>  option2List, ArrayList<type you define>  option3List,ArrayList<type you define> option4List) {

}
    public int getCount(){
        return NumberOfPages;
    }

    public boolean isViewFromObject(View container, Object obj) {
        return container == obj;
        // return container == (View) obj;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);
        // Declare Variables
        TextView option1, option2, option3, option4;
        // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
        option1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_option1);
        option2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_option2);
        option3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_option3);
        option4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_option4);
        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        option1.setText(option1List.get(0));
        option2.setText(option2List.get(0));
        option3.setText(option3List.get(0));
        option4.setText(option4List.get(0));
        // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object obj) {
       container.removeView((LinearLayout)obj);
    }
}
```